# Making Activity.Property available in context

Tags: botframework

Using the Activity.Properties to send custom property info to the Bot. I can see that the values in the MessageController, once it passed to the dialgue then the Context.Activity doesnt contain Properties property. Any idea ?

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dc/d2f/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_connector_1_1_activity.html#a0b5aff513cb633353c8f6766a214a4cb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply downcasting like below should solve this problem for you.

```
Activity a = (Activity) context.Activity;
```